# How to include a small and lightweight standalone application inside a web page in django?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

I need to add a currency converter and a calculator to my website that runs on the client side.
something similar to a servlet in java.

Comment: And what is your problem? Do you not know which pre-written solution to use? Do you not know how to embed something you have already selected? Do you want to know how to completely write your own?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a client-side "whatever" to a django project is no different than adding an image, or a video, or anything else. Django doesn't particularly care what you put into your templates. It simply renders the templates server-side to parse your template language code, and then serves up a normal web page to the client.

So the answer to your question is... Do whatever you would normally do in an html page to embed your chosen solution into the page.

The only django-specific issues here could be how to source the path to the media using template tags, which is also no different than sourcing static content like images, javascript, and css. You can read more about that on the django docs: [Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)